# VBA dynamically populate nested data structure

Tags: vba, dictionary, multidimensional-array, collections, nested

I have a few SQL tables, some which are linked, that I would like to query once and store locally in a single variable. I can't predict the length of the data ahead of time so I need a dynamic data structure.

Example data I'm querying:

Table 1

```
NameA
Red
Green
Blue
```

Table 2

```
NameA   NameB
Red     A
Red     B
Red     C
Blue    D
Blue    E
Green   F
```

Table 3

```
NameA   NameC
Red     One
Blue    Two
Blue    Three
Blue    Four
Blue    Five
Green   Six
Green   Seven
```

I need to be able to filter and access NameB and NameC based on NameA values. I would prefer a nested dictionary structure where I could query like below:

```
Table1("0") 'will equal "Red"
Table2("Red")("0") 'will equal "A"
Table2("Blue")("1") 'will equal "E"
Table3("Green")("1") 'will equal "Seven"
'note: point here is data structure, not order of results
```

I have tried using VBA's nested dictionaries but have been unable to get around the lack of a "deep copy" function. One algorithm I wrote:

```
With SqlQueryResult
    i = 0
    Do Until .EOF
        Call Table1.Add(CStr(i), .Fields(0).Value)
        i = i + 1
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

For Each key In Table1.Keys
    SqlQueryResult = GetResultsFromQuery(SELECT NameB WHERE NameA = Table1(key))
    With SqlQueryResult
        i = 0
        Do Until .EOF
            Call TempDict.Add(CStr(i), .Fields(0).Value)
            i = i + 1
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    Set Table2(Table1(key)) = TempDict
    TempDict.RemoveAll
Next key
```

Unfortunately assigning a Dict to another Dict only sets a reference and doesn't actually copy over data -- when I delete TempDict, the nested data from Table2 is also removed.

I also can't have a new dictionary per "branch" in the nest structure as I need this data to be available at a module-level scope, and therefore need to define these in the top of the module before program execution.

I've looked at multi-dimentional dynamic arrays - these can't be assigned to a parent structure like a dictionary. I also can't predict the size of each of these tables, e.g. Table1 might be 5/20/100/etc in size, Red may have 2/5/100/etcetc results in Table 2, Blue have 1/20/etcetc results in Table 2. Redim only works on a single dimension in an array.

I've had a brief look at Collections as well, and I am not sure these are viable.

I don't have much experience with classes and I would rather avoid a very involved process - I want it to be easy to add linked and unliked (i.e. data linked to Table 1, like Table 2 and 3, vs stand-alone data not related to any other table) to this program should I need to in the future. (My benchmark for "easy" is a pandas dataframe in python).

Comment: A dictionary comes to mind that has Keys from Table A and a CSV array as Items, like Red = "A,One". You could then address each item like Split(Red)(0) or Split(Red)(1). Could this idea work for you?

Comment: Its a very simple task to create a wrapper class for a Scripting dictionary that implements a clone method.  Even without a wrapper class you can still extract arrays of the Keys and Values and work with these.

Comment: @Variatus That would actually work in this case, yes, and it's nice and simple. However, I'm not also sure of whether in the future I would need to incorporate 3+ nested levels as opposed to 2 right now, which I don't think this method could accomodate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple wrapper class for scripting dictionaries which implements a clone method.  This should work fine with primitive datatypes.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type State

    Dict                               As scripting.Dictionary

End Type



Private s                              As State

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set s.Dict = New scripting.Dictionary

End Sub


Public Function Clone()

    Dim myClone As scripting.Dictionary
    Set myClone = New scripting.Dictionary

    Dim myKey As Variant
    For Each myKey In s.Dict

        myClone.Add myKey, s.Dict.Item(myKey)

    Next

    Set Clone = myClone

End Function


Public Property Get Item(ByVal Key As Variant) As Variant
    Item = s.Dict.Item(Key)
End Property

Public Property Set Item(ByVal Key As Variant, ByVal Value As Variant)
    s.Dict.Item(Key) = Value
End Property


Public Sub Add(ByVal Key As Variant, ByVal Item As Variant)
    s.Dict.Add Key, Item
End Sub
```

You will now be able to say

```
Set Table2.Item(Table1.Item(key)) = TempDict.Clone
```

Comment: Had to do a bit of googling to figure out how I utilise this, and then was stuck for a few more mins due to some errors that came up ("dictionary" is spelt wrong in the Clone function). The nested dictionaries look to be holding the data as I needed - big thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the mispelling.  My fingers-brain interface is showing its age....